# sqlite.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataframe, csv

I am working on this as an assignment but I ran into this error. The code is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

Customers = pd.read_csv (r'/content/customers.csv')  
dfc = pd.DataFrame(data=Customers, columns= ['CustomerID','CustomerName','ContactNo'])

Orders = pd.read_csv (r'/content/orders.csv')
dfo = pd.DataFrame(data=Orders, columns= ['OrderID','CustomerID','OrderDate'])

OrderDetails = pd.read_csv (r'/content/order_details.csv')
dfd = pd.DataFrame(data=OrderDetails, columns= ['OrderID','ProductID','Quantity'])

Products = pd.read_csv (r'/content/products.csv')
dfp = pd.DataFrame(data=Products, columns= ['ProductID','ProductName','UnitPrice'])

# Connect to SQL Server
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Insert DataFrame to Tables
for row in dfc.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO business.db.Customer (CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactNo)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                (row.CustomerID, 
                row.CustomerName,
                row.ContactNo)
                )
    
for row in dfo.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO business.db.Order (OrderID,CustomerID,OrderDate)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                (row.OrderID, 
                row.CustomerID,
                row.OrderDate)
                )
    
for row in dfp.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO business.db.Product (ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                (row.ProductID, 
                row.ProductName,
                row.UnitPrice)
                ) 
    
for row in dfd.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO business.db.OrderDetails (OrderID,ProductID,Quantity)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                (row.OrderID, 
                row.ProductID,
                row.Quantity)
                )
    
connection.commit()
```

When I run the code on Google Colaboratory I get an error message like this:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-1726ecf71e09> in <module>()
     40                 (row.CustomerID, 
     41                 row.CustomerName,
---> 42                 row.ContactNo)
     43                 )
     44 

OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. Yes, I also know that there are 3 arguments given for the function when it only accepts 2. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps the  real problem is table names `business.db.Customer`. If this is sqlite, then a table name with special characters needs to be enclosed in something, eg quotes `"` sqlite only uses db name prefix in the case attached database (or temp database); even if `business.db` is an attached database, the whole phrase needs to be enclosed because of the `.`s

Answer (score 0):

try using string formatting instead

```
(f'''INSERT INTO business.db.Customer (CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactNo) 
   VALUES ('{row.CustomerID}','{row.CustomerName}','{row.ContactNo}')''')
```

for integer types remove ' '